# How do I redirect users from Japan to a certain subsite?

Tags: 7

I want users from Japan to be redirected to *www.example.com/test2* when they hit *www.example.com/test1*. In the menu only Test1 is visible.

What tools do I need? I tried to insert a PHP script into the header with the 'Add to Header' module, but for that I need the directory of the sites, which I do not have.
I can also set Geo Rules, but then I have two sites with different URLs which are invisible and unaccessible for those excluded, but the 'Access denied' message is not preferable.

Comment: Have you got any kind of multilingual architecture set up (i18n for example)?

Comment: You shouldnt be redirecting users in subsite, add GeoIP redirect rules in example.com instead of example.com/test1

Comment: @Chapabu 
I have no such thing, as the main language is always English

Comment: @kantu
I don't want to redirect from the main page directly, the main page should be accessable for everyone. But when users from Japan click on the test-link they have to be redirected to their version of the test-link.

Answer (score 1):

You can have country based redirection to any internal, or exernal path using the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context), [Context GeoIP](http://drupal.org/project/context_geoip), and the [Context Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/context_redirect) modules.

Answer (score 0):

try looking up in the .htaccess and do the changes, modify the rewrite rules..once you are in the .htaccess just go through the file once..you will understand as all is commented pretty nicely...

Comment: Hello, and welcome on Drupal Answers. What changes do the file exactly need? Saying to alter the .htaccess file without to say which changes are necessary is not exactly answering the question.